# how to remove memory monitor from NetBeans 13 toolbar?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

Is there a way to delete the memory use/garbage collection widget from the toolbar in NetBeans 13?  I don't know it's proper name and not finding it under Tools > Options.  The constant updating/noise is driving me nuts.

[image: memory usage widget]

Comment: You can hide the graph using the main menu: View > Toolbars > Performance - but that will also hide the additional 2 icons (for profiling) to the right of the memory usage graph. I don't believe there is any way to _only_ hide the graph. That may or may not be acceptable to you.

Comment: You can also explore creating a custom toolbar using View > Toolbars > Customize. Maybe that allows you to hide the Performance icons (as noted above) and then add back the profiling icons you may still want to see. I have not tried that, myself.

Comment: Beautiful!  Like removing a splinter. ;)  Thanks a million andrewJames!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here is my first comment as an answer, since that worked for you, and may help others:*

You can hide the graph using the main menu: View > Toolbars > Performance - but that will also hide the additional 2 icons (for profiling) to the right of the memory usage graph.

I don't believe there is any way to only hide the graph.